# When I should use the CARDS term when talking about APIs?

Tags: rest, twitter, service, google-glass

I am documenting an API and I have seen that CARDS are mentioned in the Twitter API documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) and also in a presentation on Google Glass API (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=JpWmGX55a40). Does an “official” standard definition of CARDS, within the Web Services context, exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official HTML meta data standard for CARDS. You can see the list of offical meta tags in the HTML5 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names

Twitter Cards are a way for twitter to parse and make sense of HTML content in order for presentation in your twitter feed. I would think of them more in terms of HTML instead of in the context of web services.

But if I try to guess your intention, in the context of web services I would just consider and serve from an api/service the data needed to populate the CARDS meta data as defined by Twitter or Youtubes specs. That way a consumer would have the data necessary to generate the HTML that Twitter or Youtube would consume.